# Sorting the String Array based on given pattern in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, design-patterns

My input string array is like below:

> String[] arr =    {"2T1BURHE1JCO24154C",
>                      "2TABURHE1JC024154C", 
>                      "JTDKARFP5H3055472C", 
>                      "2T2BURHE1JCO24154C",
>                      "JTDKARFP1H3056246C"};

The output array should be as below:

```
           {"JTDKARFP1H3056246C", 
           "JTDKARFP5H3055472C", 
           "2TABURHE1JC024154C", 
           "2T1BURHE1JCO24154C", 
           "2T2BURHE1JCO24154C"}
```

Here the priority is given in the below pattern:

> [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]

When I use the Arrays.sort(arr) in Java it sorts the array in dictionary pattern and gives the below output:

> [2T1BURHE1JCO24154C, 2T2BURHE1JCO24154C, 2TABURHE1JC024154C, JTDKARFP1H3056246C, JTDKARFP5H3055472C]

How could I achieve this in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try creating a custom comparator that compares the letter's position in the "priority array". This question is pretty broad as is though.

Comment: String will always sort() based on order in its compareTo() method. You need to provide your own custom Comparator to the sort method if you need custom sorting.

Comment: Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder()); simple isn't it?

Comment: RadixSort you have to use

Answer (score 4):

You need custom a Comparator, you can do it by compare the character's position in the `order`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = {"2T1BURHE1JCO24154C",
            "2TABURHE1JC024154C",
            "JTDKARFP5H3055472C",
            "2T2BURHE1JCO24154C",
            "JTDKARFP1H3056246C"};

    String order = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    Arrays.sort(arr, (first, second) -> {
        for (int index = 0; index < second.length(); index++) {
            int charFirst = (int) (first.charAt(index));
            int charSecond = (int) (second.charAt(index));
            if (order.indexOf(charFirst) >  order.indexOf(charSecond)) {
                return 1; 
            } else if (order.indexOf(charFirst) <  order.indexOf(charSecond)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });

    for (String s : arr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

output:

```
JTDKARFP1H3056246C
JTDKARFP5H3055472C
2TABURHE1JC024154C
2T1BURHE1JCO24154C
2T2BURHE1JCO24154C
```

Answer (score 3):

looks like Johns works i think this is a little more clean.

```
String order = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
Comparator<String> c = (s1, s2) -> {
        int minLen = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
            char s1Char = s1.charAt(i);
            char s2Char = s2.charAt(i);
            if (s1Char == s2Char) {
                //if characters are the same skip
                continue;
            } else {
                //if the characters are diff get precedence
                return order.indexOf(s1Char) - order.indexOf(s2Char);
            }
        }
        // if all chars are the same the longer one is last
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    };
```

While above works i think the indexOf op is not the best. better solution is to just alter the standard compareTo function:

```
Comparator<String> c = (s1, s2) -> {
        int len1 = s1.length();
        int len2 = s2.length();
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
        int k = 0;
        while (k < lim) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(k);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(k);
            if (c1 != c2) {
                if ((c1 >= 'A' && c2 >= 'A') ^ (c1 <= '9' && c2 <= '9')) {
                    return c1 - c2;
                } else return c2 - c1;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    };
```

most of the functionality is the same. but instead we determine if we are comparing letter to letter or number to number  do normal comparison. else reverse to put letters before numbers.

*final edit. don't make char arrays just get the chars from the string.

comparison from old method to new on 1M items is >2x faster.  800ms compared to 1800ms

Comment: this one is better

Comment: might also want to upcase the strings just in case.